# Generic types in class definitions and subclasses in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I don't know the terminology of what I am trying to do, which makes asking the question difficult. Here is a minimal example:

```
abstract class Obj() {
    abstract fun checkIssues() : List<String>

    fun runRules(rules: List<Rule<Obj>>): List<String> {
        return rules.mapNotNull {
            it.check(this)
        }
    }
}

class Field(): Obj(){
    companion object {
        val rules = listOf(MissingResetRule())
    }
    override fun checkIssues(): List<String> = runRules(rules)
}

class MissingResetRule : Rule<Field>() {
    override fun check(obj: Field): String? = ""
}

abstract class Rule<T: Obj> {
    abstract fun check(obj: T): String?
}
```

The problem is that `List<MissingResetRule>` is not a subclass of`List<Rule<Obj>>` or to be more precise, `MissingRule` is not a subclass of `Rule<Obj>`. This means `runRules(rules)` complains about the types being wrong. But `Field` is a subclass of `Obj` so I would have thought that `Rule<Field>` would be a subclass of `Rule<Obj>`. I can't seem to figure out how to tell the compiler that everything is valid here.

I have read the documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html many times and can't understand how it applies to the code above.

Comment: Use `abstract class Rules<out T: Obj>`. You can read up on covariance vs. invariance to understand why this is necessary in this case.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but then the check function because T is declared as out but used as an in. Am I basically out of luck here?

Comment: Oh I missed that when I was looking at this on my phone earlier. Yes, you are out of luck. If `T` is used in an `in` position, it does not make logical sense to say a `Rule<Field>` is a subtype of `Rule<Obj>`. If it let you do that, you'd get a ClassCastException at runtime when passing an `Obj` that is not a `Field` to a `Rule<Field>` that is supposedly a `Rule<Obj>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you try to have a function `runRules` that exactly get the rules of the corresponding type. Then make this function generic:

```
abstract class Obj() {
    abstract fun checkIssues() : List<String>
}

fun <T : Obj> T.runRules(rules: List<Rule<T>>): List<String> {
    return rules.mapNotNull {
        it.check(this)
    }
}

class Field(): Obj(){
    companion object {
        val rules = listOf(MissingResetRule())
    }
    override fun checkIssues(): List<String> = runRules(rules)
}

class MissingResetRule : Rule<Field>() {
    override fun check(obj: Field): String? = ""
}

abstract class Rule<T: Obj> {
    abstract fun check(obj: T): String?
}
```